# Disabling choices after a selection has been made with select tags?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm building a web form and I currently have five 'drop-down' menus (using the select tag) that allow users to choose a value from 0-5. It looks like this:

```
              Choose one:
                    <select name="choose_one" required>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>    
                    </select>
```

Is there anything I can do to disable a certain number from being chosen again if it is chosen on a select menu in other menus? Meaning, if I select 1 on the first drop-down menu I come across, I wouldn't be able to select it again on the others.

A potential solution I was considering was making a table of radio buttons. When a user selects a number, it disables that whole row of numbers. However I'm not really sure if I could do this in HTML. I think I'd need to use JS/JQuery.

[image: Test table!]

One of the issues here is that 0 should be able to be selected multiple times, but a column needs to be disabled after a value for that column has been selected. The 0 field could be checkboxes, but then the style wouldn't be the same as the radio buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use same name for radio buttons in one cloumn.

For example

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>item 1</td>
    <td>item 2</td>
    <td>item 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="item1" value="0" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="item2" value="0" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="item3" value="0" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="item1" value="1" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="item2" value="1" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="item3" value="1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="item1" value="2" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="item2" value="2" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="item3" value="2" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### Update

```js
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
  var selectedValue = $(this).val() ;
  $("input[value="+selectedValue+"]").each(function(){
    if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).prop('disabled', true);
   }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>item 1</td>
        <td>item 2</td>
        <td>item 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="item1" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="item2" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="item3" value="0" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="item1" value="1" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="item2" value="1" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="item3" value="1" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="item1" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="item2" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="item3" value="2" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I may be wrong but I think OP only needs one value selected per column as well (unless it's 0) not just one per row.

Comment: He says "One of the issues here is that 0 should be able to be selected multiple times, but a column needs to be disabled after a value for that column has been selected. " So one value per column clears.

Comment: Is there anyway to disable that field after selection though? For example I wouldn't want item 1 and item 3 to have the same value of 1. This does solve part of the issue though.

Comment: Hey @Bilal, just another quick question. If I were to switch the ranking of an item in the same column, how can I re-enable the disabled items? i.e. I select item 2 at ranking 1 but then switch it to ranking 2, options for item1 and 3 are now disabled for ranking 1. I tried using `if(!$(this).is(':checked') == false { $(this).prop('disabled', false)` but it didn't work.

Comment: this is because when radio is disabled you click event will not fire again. In this case you need to convert radio inputs to checkboxes. Change it carefully, you have to edit js also.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what @Bilal proposed. I added a data-col attribute for each column as well and I use this to disable the other radio buttons in the same column.  There is probably a better way to do this but this is off the top of my head.
HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>item 1</td>
  <td>item 2</td>
  <td>item 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>0</td>
  <td><input data-col="1" type="radio" name="item1" value="0" /></td>
  <td><input data-col="2" type="radio" name="item2" value="0" /></td>
  <td><input data-col="3" type="radio" name="item3" value="0" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td><input data-col="1" type="radio" name="item1" value="1" /></td>
  <td><input data-col="2" type="radio" name="item2" value="1" /></td>
  <td><input data-col="3" type="radio" name="item3" value="1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td><input data-col="1" type="radio" name="item1" value="2" /></td>
  <td><input data-col="2" type="radio" name="item2" value="2" /></td>
  <td><input data-col="3" type="radio" name="item3" value="2" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
var all = $('input[type="radio"]');
all.on('change' function(){
  var col =$(this).attr('data-col');
  $('[data-col="'+col+'"]').prop('disabled', true);
  $(this).prop('disabled',false);
});
```

Comment: For some reason Notepad++ isn't picking up the data-col addition, but this helps me a lot which figuring out the script needed to disable the fields.